# Finiteness of a series coming from expectation formula

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, expected-value, conditional-expectation, experimental-mathematics

I have found that if
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
&u_i=\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{c-1}\frac{1}{c}\binom{i-1}{c-j-1}
q^{i+j-c}p^{c-j},\\
&s_i=\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^i u_r,
\end{array}
$$
then
$$
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty i[s_i^m-(s_i-u_i)^m]
$$
converges (I have tested on the computer). But so far, I've not been able to prove it.

The parameters $c$ and $m$ are natural numbers such that $c\geq 2$ and $m\geq 1$.

Can anyone, please, lend me a hand?